# How to *dynamically* specify which key to use for git?

Tags: ssh, git, ssh-keys

All solutions I've seen so far assume that I want to use a certain key statically. Whereas I want to use a key dynamically: I want to specify what key to use as I run a git command every time. One time I want to be able to use one key, next time -- another.

I've tried this:

```
# 1
$ git pull origin master -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
error: unknown switch `i'
usage: git pull [<options>] [<repository> [<refspec>...]]


# 2
$ git pull -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 origin master 
error: unknown switch `i'
usage: git pull [<options>] [<repository> [<refspec>...]]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You can use something like $ GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/user1.key” git pull/push ...

Comment: @ALex_hha what to do with `GIT_SSH_COMMAND`?

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/232373/144961

Answer (score 6):

You can do this using the `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` environment variable:

`GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519" git pull origin master`

Comment: and then I'll have to create a new env. variable if I want to pull from other branch or origin?

Comment: No, there is no need. The GIT_SSH_COMMAND will be "visible" only for this particular command.

Comment: that's not working. if I add "-v" to it, it says "debug1: Offering public key: RSA ...."

Comment: @Vano are you sure you don't have something in your SSH config overriding? Try using `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -F /dev/null -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519" git pull origin master` to ignore any config you have.